# Single Source of Truth (DRY) to validate AngularJS Forms on client- and server-side

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I am planning a new project based on AngularJS on the client and let's say Java or PHP on the server.

The AngularJS application provides a simple form for registration, e.g. username, first and last name, e-mail, password and confirm password.

I am currently searching for the best way to define the validation for the form's input data.

On the one hand, the definition should impact the client application. For example, the validation defines that the username must have 4 to 14 characters and AngularJS should display an error on invalid input without sending a validation request to the server first. I imagine that AngularJS reads the definition file (maybe JSON or XML) on start up and enforces those requirements on the client-side.

On the other hand, the server-side code, which receives the submitted form data, should also rely on the same definition file in order to validate the passed form data.

Of course, there are some validations the client cannot perform without the server, for instance, whether an unique username was entered.

**My question is**, whether there is a framework, extension, best practice, or recipe how to implement such a Single Source of Truth for form input validation when using AngularJS on the client-side and for example Java or PHP on the server-side?

Comment: There are of course, many libraries, frameworks, etc. for pretty much every possible computer science problem. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for those external resources, since everyone will have a different answer based on their experience. See the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found http://json-schema.org/ and will stick to the implementations https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema for the server-side Java validation and https://github.com/zaggino/z-schema for the client-side JavaScript validation.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Spring on the back-end, Angular on the front, and I have wondered the same thing while doing validation, but there isn't any type of framework for this. Your best bet is to use HTTP standards to communicate errors from the back end.

For example, if you complete client-side validation (username and password are long enough, not null, etc) and then send that data to the back end to make sure the username isn't already taken, you would then want to respond with an appropriate HTTP status code along with whatever else is in your response. In this case, a `200` status if everything was okay on the back-end, or something like a `409` for conflict. HTTP is likely the standard you are looking for, and it still allows you incredible flexibility.

Then, you can handle these status codes within Angular and do different things client-side after handling the logic.